How to add a border around a masked image using canvas in JavaScript?
I am trying to mask an image using another image (acting as a mask) and add a border around the shape defined by the mask using the  element in JavaScript.
Here's the code I'm using:
function applyFiltersAndConvertToBase64(imageUrl, materialImage) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const maskImg = new Image();
        const mainImg = new Image();
        maskImg.crossOrigin = "anonymous"; // Important for cross-origin images
        mainImg.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

        let imagesLoaded = 0;

        const onLoad = () => {
            imagesLoaded++;
            if (imagesLoaded === 2) {
                // Create a canvas element
                const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                // Set canvas dimensions to the size of the mask image
                canvas.width = maskImg.width;
                canvas.height = maskImg.height;

                // Draw the mask image
                ctx.drawImage(maskImg, 0, 0);

                // Change composite mode to use the mask for clipping
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';

                // Draw the main image to be clipped
                ctx.drawImage(mainImg, 0, 0, maskImg.width, maskImg.height);

                // Reset composite operation
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

                // Convert canvas to Base64
                const base64Image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                resolve(base64Image);
            }
        };

        maskImg.onload = onLoad;
        mainImg.onload = onLoad;

        maskImg.onerror = reject;
        mainImg.onerror = reject;

        // Set the sources
        maskImg.src = imageUrl; // Mask image
        mainImg.src = materialImage; // Main image
    });
}


This function works fine for applying the mask and clipping the main image, but I’m struggling to add a border around the mask’s shape. The border either appears as a rectangle or does not appear at all, depending on the approach I’ve tried.
How can I add a border that follows the shape defined by the mask, rather than the canvas' rectangular boundaries? I want the border to trace the exact edges of the mask.
Any help would be appreciated!
How can I add a border that follows the shape defined by the mask, rather than the canvas' rectangular boundaries? I want the border to trace the exact edges of the mask.
